# Forward packets to another IP

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, iptables

I ama using a VPN to connect to my work network. The problem is that the VPN doesn't have a route for the subnet I want to reach (192.168.24.0/24). I am able to ping another subnet (192.168.2.0/24), in which the gateway is 192.168.2.254. I know that the 192.168.2.254 gateway is able to reach the subnet I want.
Is it possible to forward All packets with destination 192.168.24.0/24, to the host 192.168.2.254 using something like ip tables?

Comment: Have you asked the people at work for assistance?

Comment: I would like to give it a try before asking them

Comment: I think you would need access to their VPN system to set up the IP address you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit light on details, so my answer is a bit generic.

The "correct" solution is to get the vpn configuration files adjusted to add the route. Normally a server would push the appropriate route  however in some cases the cluent could add a route statement which would enable the route when the vpn goes up.

It is possible to do this manually - simply add a route across the vpn interface - for example using "ip route add 192.168.24.0/24 via X.X.X.X" where X.X.X.X is the IP address of the remote VPN endpoint.  (you can likely find this by doing an "ip route"and looking at the gateway associated with 192.168.2.0.

Note that for this to work, the end point needs to be able to reach  192.168.24.0/24 and 192.168.24.0 needs a generic path to the your vpn ip.  There is a high chance this will work (the default route for devices on 192.168.24.0 is via a router that can see both sides), but wont  for example, work if 192.168.24.0 is behind NAT.